# how do i find my SHA 1 for my android app in android studio?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to developing Android apps and I wanted to create a Google map inside of a Fragment. So far I've gotten the part where I need the API key and I'm confused by the instructions from the Android developer site and everything I've found online hasn't cleared my confusion.
Could someone provide me with a step by step of how to get my SHA1 fingerprint on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot obtain the API_KEY until you get your SHA1.

Click [here](http://livingcode.co/index.php/2014/04/10/android-studio-how-to-get-debug-signing-certificate-on-windows/) to get a nice tutorial that will guide you step by step with images (Specifically when you are operating on Windows 7).

Hope this would Help!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of fingerprints, debug and release.  Assuming you want a release one, then from a console window, you need to run this command to get the fingerprint

```
keytool -exportcert -alias MY_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore MY_FULL_PATH_TO_RELEASE_KEYSTORE_FILE -list -v
```

The keytool program is in your JDK bin folder.  So on Windows, something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin is where you should find keytool

Last thing to note is that MY_FULL_PATH_TO_RELEASE_KEYSTORE_FILE in the command above should be the full path to your .keystore file, including the file name

After all that, you will be finally be provided with several fingerprints, including the SHA1. You can copy that, and go back to Google Developers Console and paste it as a new line in the allowed Android Applications, with your package name added to the end, separated by a semi-colon.

Comment: as far as im aware, i believe im looking for the debug fingerprint.